# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.loggingGetPhaseMapForReading

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I'm getting null pointer exception. Don't understand what is going wrong. I have used normal JSF 2.2 with bootstrap. I don't know much about annotations so I have added manual entries in faces-config.xml file. Is there anything required?

Getting the following error in console.

```
Sep 12, 2015 10:14:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.loggingGetPhaseMapForReading(ELFlash.java:793)
at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.getPhaseMapForReading(ELFlash.java:826)
at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.isEmpty(ELFlash.java:484)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeVariables(DevTools.java:325)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.writeVariables(DevTools.java:215)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.util.DevTools.debugHtml(DevTools.java:130)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils.renderHtmlErrorPage(RenderKitUtils.java:1162)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.throwIt(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:276)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:142)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:546)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:364)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:154)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
```

Faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
version="1.2">
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>SignupBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.jsf.beans.SignupBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

Web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>JavaServerFaces</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Welcome page -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/views/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- JSF mapping -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

index.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
<title>Registration</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javacript" src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/datestyle.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>
<body class="jumbotron">
<h:form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="container">
<div class="row form-group">
<h:outputLabel class="col-md-2"value="Name"/>
<div class="col-md-3">
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{SignupBean.name}" required="true"/> 
<h:message for="name"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group">
<h:outputLabel class="col-md-2"value="Password"/>
<div class="col-md-3">
<h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{SignupBean.password}" required="true"/>
<h:message for="password"/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group">
<h:outputLabel class="col-md-2"value="Date of Birth"/>
<div class="col-md-3">
 <h:inputText id="dob" value="#{SignupBean.dob}" required="true"/>
<h:message for="dob"/>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="row form-group">
 <h:outputLabel class="col-md-2"value="Email"/>
 <div class="col-md-3">
 <h:inputText id="email" value="#{SignupBean.email}" required="true"/>

 <h:message for="email"/>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row form-group">
 <h:outputLabel class="col-md-2"value="Phone"/>
 <div class="col-md-3">
 <h:inputText id="phone" value="#{SignupBean.phone}" required="true"/>
 <h:message for="phone"/>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row form-group">
 <h:outputLabel class="col-md-2"value="Address"/>
 <div class="col-md-3">
 <h:inputText id="address" value="#{SignupBean.address}" required="true"/>
 <h:message for="address"/>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </h:form>
 </body>

 </html>
```

DisplayBean.java

```
package com.jsf.beans;

public class DisplayBean {
private String name;
private String password;
private String dob;
private String email;
private String phone;
private String address;

public DisplayBean(String name,String password,String dob,String email,String phone,String address)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.password=password;
    this.dob=dob;
    this.email=email;
    this.phone=phone;
    this.address=address;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}
public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}
public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
}
```

SignupBean.java

```
package com.jsf.beans;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SignupBean {

private String name;
private String password;
private String dob;
private String email;
private String phone;
private String address;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}
public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}
public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public static final ArrayList<DisplayBean> details = new ArrayList<DisplayBean>();
public String setDetails(){
    DisplayBean detail = new DisplayBean(name,password,dob,email,phone,address);
    details.add(detail);
    return "success";
}
}
```

Jars Added:

```
commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar
commons-chain-1.2.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
jsf-api-2.2.12.jar
jsf-impl-2.1.7.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
```

Comment: You are using JSF 1.2 version declaration in your `faces-config.xml` file. Probably you copied and pasted it from an old example. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539735/xhtml-url-pattern-causes-java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-com-sun-faces-conte) question. I also encourage you to use annotations. It is very simple and clear in JSF.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CDI injection when working with cdi managed beans (which would make sens since you are probably learning so going for the updated version makes sens).

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Mybean{
   public MyBean(){
    }
}
```

This is how you make a bean. Since the bean is managed by the container that means that the container itself instanciate those. Which also mean that you cannot instanciate those yourself and they need to have an empty constructor.

```
   public MyBean(){
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.